# How can I deploy this express server to my domain?

Tags: node.js, express, hostmonster

I feel quite silly trying to describe this issue but- i'm trying to build more full stack projects and in the process built a great little app that took votes, store the results of all the votes in a database (using SSMS), and the displayed the results. Works perfectly- locally.

I'm trying to now add this project to my website so prospective employers can use it/see it. My website is hosted on hostmonster so I made an SQL server there and change the appropriate configurations.

Well, it doesn't work and i'm 99% the reason is because of my express server. I have this server.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const databaseOperations = require('./src/database/operations')
const cors = require('cors')

const API_PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cors())

app.get('/api', async (req, res) => {
    const result = await databaseOperations.getGraphVotes();
     res.send(result)
});

app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log(`listening on port ${API_PORT}`))
```

Then in my component files i've got variables like this:

```
 const newData = await fetch('https://example.com:4000/api', {
```

(example.com being my domain of course)

My question is, do I need to set up that port somehow through hostmonster? I don't see any documentation or anything on how to do that. And I feel like I don't quite know enough to know what to search to figure this out. How do I set up this express server?

Again, it worked great when it was on my local machine but I can't figure out how this works through a service like hostmonster.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There could be some possible reasons why you can't access the Node express server.

1. Your server does not start when you run the application - it could be due to an incorrect entry point given in the host monster configuration.
2. It does start and you should check the logs to validate it - it is not accessible from the outside.

Solution:

1. You should check the logs and validate if your node server is serving the request - this message would be enough: listening on port 4000
2. Make sure the DNS entry you created for `https://example.com` points to the correct port of the server running in hostmonster environment. Also, check the port on the firewall if it is accessible or blocked in hostmonster.

You can check [DNS ENTRY](https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/dns-management-add-edit-or-delete-dns-entries) to make your DNS entry to the correct application and [FIREWALL UPDATE](https://my.hostmonster.com/hosting/help/configserver-security-firewall).